# How to generate code for an optional Java exception in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, exception

I have some code that is parsing an int from a string:

`int number = Integer.parseInt(a[0]);`

there is no guarantee that the string I will receive is well formed and this may throw a NumberFormatException. However, as this exception is optional, Eclipse does not give me a light bulb for generating it.

Is there a menu or context menu option to wrap an exception of a method beneath the cursor or carrot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highlight the block you want to enwrap, go to the top menu under `Source`. Choose `Surround with Try / Catch Block`.

It will automatically indent the code and list the found exceptions. I think the `NumberFormatException` will be listed automatically.

This is basically the same as with UncheckedExceptions, except that with UncheckedExceptions Eclipse will automatically highlight the line as it is a Java Error to ignore (not catch nor rethrow) a checked exception.
You probably have used the QuickFix Menu (usually STRG+1 as hotkey, or mouse hover over the error).
The menu item above will work even without an error (and thus no error you could use QuickFix for)

Comment: The missing piece was that I needed to highlight the entire expression, not just the method. This is perfect, thanks!

Comment: Well, you can wrap multiple lines if you want. But highlighting less could cause Eclipse to missunderstand you. If it's just a part of the line, it could either decide to widen the selection to the whole line or to disable the menu item - which wouldn't be what you want. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

It wont as `NumberFormatException` is a `RuntimeException`.

Imagine all the hard work eclipse would have to do to catch null pointer exceptions.Eclipse would only tell you about checked Throwables

Comment: My question is about how to generate code for an exception not to have Eclipse catch it.